# selected con razor

Tags: asp.net, .net, razor

quiero saber como hacer un selected en un Dropdownlist,probe asignando un valor de la vista pero me aparece como valor extra.

modelo:

```
 public List<SelectListItem> ListaMeses()
    {
        return new List<SelectListItem>
            {
                new SelectListItem { Text = string.Empty, Value = "00"},
                new SelectListItem { Text = "Enero", Value = "01"},
                new SelectListItem { Text = "Febrero", Value = "02"},
                new SelectListItem { Text = "Marzo", Value = "03"},
                new SelectListItem { Text = "Abril", Value = "04"},
                new SelectListItem { Text = "Mayo", Value = "05"},
                new SelectListItem { Text = "Junio", Value = "06"},
                new SelectListItem { Text = "Julio", Value = "07"},
                new SelectListItem { Text = "Agosto", Value = "08"},
                new SelectListItem { Text = "Septiembre", Value = "09"},
                new SelectListItem { Text = "Octubre", Value = "10"},
                new SelectListItem { Text = "Noviembre", Value = "11"},
                new SelectListItem { Text = "Diciembre", Value = "12"}
            };
    }



  public ActionResult Control()
        {
            Common commons = new Common();
            ViewBag.anio = commons.ListaAnios();
            ViewBag.meses = commons.ListaMeses();
            ViewBag.dias = commons.ListaDias();

            return View();
        }
```

Vista

```
<div class="fld  col-md-2">
                @Html.DropDownList("mes", (List<SelectListItem>)ViewBag.meses, new { @class = "chosen-select", placeholder = "Seleccionar Mes", @default = "07" })
            </div>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

En tu vista lo estas castiando a un `List<SelectListItem>`
y deberia ser un `IEnumerable<SelectListItem>`.

Te dejo el ejemplo:

```
@Html.DropDownList("mes", (IEnumerable<SelectListItem>)ViewBag.meses, new { @class = "chosen-select", placeholder = "Seleccionar Mes", @default = "07" })
```

Otra opción seria:

```
@Html.DropDownList("mes", new SelectList((IEnumerable)ViewBag.meses, "Value", "Text"), new { @class = "chosen-select", placeholder = "Seleccionar Mes", @default = "07" })
```

Si necesitas que una opción en especifico salga siempre selecionada, por ejemplo: la opción de enero, cuando creas el item lo especificas.

```
new SelectListItem { Text = "Enero", Value = "01", Selected = true }
```

Si lo que nesecitas es selecionar el valo que viene del modelo entonces haces:

```
@Html.DropDownListFor(model => model.mes, new SelectList((IEnumerable)ViewBag.meses, "Value", "Text"), new { @class = "chosen-select", placeholder = "Seleccionar Mes", @default = "07" })
```

Comment: lo voy a agregar, pero el tema,  es cuando quiero que aparezca seleccionada un opción, es lo que no puedo hacer. Saludos...

Comment: Cual opcion quieres que aparesca selecionada?

Comment: el text="Enero"